# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) while create my user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I know there is a lot of question about that but I can't find an answer for my case.

So, I build a Rails 4 API, I try to create a User with a post JSON request.

Here some pieces of my code :

user.rb :

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  has_secure_password

  belongs_to :current_position, :class_name => "Position", foreign_key: "position_current_id"
  has_many :positions
  searchkick locations: ["location"]

  def search_data
    attributes.merge location: [current_position.latitude, current_position.longitude]
  end

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json, :html
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session,
                         if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format =~ %r{application/json} }
end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
class Api::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render :json => {:token => user.authentication_token, :email =>user.email}, :status=>201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json =>user.errors, :status=>422
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username)
  end
end
```

So I try to send a request with the following params

```
{"user":{"email":"user5@gmail.com", "password" : "123456789", "password_confirmation" : "123456789", "username" : "toto"}}
```

But I get the following error :

```
started POST "/signup.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-30 13:27:02 +0100
Processing by Api::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"user5@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"toto"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"user5@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"toto"}}}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
  app/controllers/api/registrations_controller.rb:19:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/billey_b/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/billey_b/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/billey_b/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/billey_b/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (17.9ms)
```

So I'm a little bit desperate about that so if someone have some explenations to clarify me, It would be great. Thank's

EDIT :

My User schema

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                default: "", null: false
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.datetime "birth"
    t.string   "status"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "encrypted_password"
    t.string   "authentication_token"
    t.integer  "position_current_id"
  end
```

I also use this gem https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication

Comment: Shouldn't it be instead of "user = User.new(user_params)" --> "user = User.new(params[:user])" ?

Comment: which is line 19 of the registrations controller?

Comment: @epergo if I do your method I get  ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
  app/controllers/api/registrations_controller.rb:18:in `create'

@dax line 19 is user.save

Comment: What attributes do you have on your User model? [Some attribute names are not allowed.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725707/wrong-number-of-arguments-0-for-1-with-activerecordsave)

Comment: I updated my question to add the User attributes

Comment: How do you send the request? Are you manually creating the params object?

Comment: I send my request just like that http://imgur.com/agP07DQ

Comment: Try to send the request like this: {user: {email: "user5@gmail.com", password: "123456789", password_confirmation: "123456789", username: "toto"}}

Comment: @epergo with this I get Unexpected token, cause of the missing quotes =/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, I replaced :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  has_secure_password

  belongs_to :current_position, :class_name => "Position", foreign_key: "position_current_id"
  has_many :positions
  searchkick locations: ["location"]

  def search_data
    attributes.merge location: [current_position.latitude, current_position.longitude]
  end

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

By this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  has_secure_password

  belongs_to :current_position, :class_name => "Position", foreign_key: "position_current_id"
  has_many :positions
  searchkick locations: ["location"]

  def search_data
    attributes.merge location: [current_position.latitude, current_position.longitude]
  end
end
```

It's now working